# How to concatenate two template files into one file and pass onto ECS container task definition in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have two template files. I want to merge these template files into one and pass them onto the ECS attribute **container_definitions** in the **aws_ecs_task_definition** resource.

Terraform Version => v0.14.9

**nginx.tpl.json:**

```
 [
    {
        "name": "nginx",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

**redis.json.tpl:**

```
 [
    {
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/peakon/redis:6.0.5",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 6379,
                "hostPort": 6379,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

When combined two template files manually like below it is working. But with Terraform [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html) or [format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/format.html) getting errors.

```
 [
    {
        "name": "nginx",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/peakon/redis:6.0.5",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 6379,
                "hostPort": 6379,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

```
data "template_file" "ecs_task" {
  template = format("%s%s",file("./ecs/templates/nginx.json.tpl"),
                            file("./ecs/templates/redis.json. tpl")
              )
} => Here I need to combine the two template files and then pass them onto the container_definitions to the below resource.
```

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "testapp" {
  family                = "testapp"
  network_mode          = "awsvpc"
  cpu                   = 256
  memory                = 512
  container_definitions = data.template_file.ecs_task.rendered # I'm getting the following error.
}
```

**Error:**`invalid character '}' looking for the beginning of object key string`

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: If you do it manually, will it work? Thus, the issue is only with automated concatenation?

Comment: @Marcin, Yes. If I do it manually it worked.

Comment: Can you show the file manually joined?

Comment: @Marcin, 

This is how the file
`
   [
    {
        "name": "nginx",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/peakon/redis:6.0.5",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 6379,
                "hostPort": 6379,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
`

Comment: Can you edit your question with properly formatted  example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Remove brackets from your files

```
    {
        "name": "nginx",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    }
```

and

```
    {
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/peakon/redis:6.0.5",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 6379,
                "hostPort": 6379,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then instead of  `"%s%s"`. Seems you are missing **comma**: `"[%s,%s]"`.

Comment: I tried with **comma**. Did not work for me. Is it working for you?

Comment: @Jwary Comma is what you are using in your example.

Comment: I used **comma** when I combining two JSON template files manually. But using  `"%s,%s"` did not help.